# Find longest consecutive characters in 2D array

Tags: code-golf, array

**Challenge**

Given a 2D array, find the length and direction of all the longest consecutive characters.

- If there are ties, output *every* possible winning combination in any order, (winners can overlap with other winners)
- Zero "0" is a special padding character which cannot be a winner.
- Code golf rules apply, shortest code wins.

**Output:** n,m,d

(Where *n* is the identified character of length *m* in *d* direction)

Valid characters for *d*: `/|\-.` *See below examples to interpret meaning.*

**Input:** The 2D array input should be in either of the following format, (your preference):

Option 1:

```
123
456
789
```

Option 2*:

```
[["123"],["456"],["789"]]
```

*or any combination of "{[()]}" characters can be used, with whitespace characters ignored outside of quotes. Quotes can be single or double. The array must read left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

**Assumptions**

- The shape of the array will always be rectangular or square
- There will always be at least one non-zero character
- Array characters will only be alphanumeric

**Examples**

1.

```
0000000
0111100
0000000
```

> 1,4,-

2.

```
00000000
aaaa0000
00bbbbb0
```

> b,5,-

3.

```
0y00x000
aayxaaaz
00xy000z
0x00y00z
x0000y0z
```

> x,5,/
>
> y,5,\

*(in any order)

4.

```
1111
1111
1111
```

> 1,4,-
>
> 1,4,-
>
> 1,4,-

5.

```
ccc
cwc
ccc
```

> c,3,-
>
> c,3,-
>
> c,3,|
>
> c,3,|

*(in any order)

6.

```
9
```

> 9,1,.

7.

```
ab
cd
```

> a,1,.
>
> b,1,.
>
> c,1,.
>
> d,1,.

*(in any order)

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the `.`. What's the expected result of a 2x2 square of 3 `1`s and a `0`?

Comment: @Neil The dot just means it doesn't have a direction because the longest string of characters, is of length one. A 2x2 matrix of 3 1s and a 0, would be: "1,2,| and 1,2,-"

Comment: Are we restricted to those 4 characters for `d` or can we use any 4 characters of our choosing?

Comment: Why restrict the input format to a string, instead of just saying it is a 2D array and letting the site defaults take care of it?

Comment: Suggested test case: `ab\ncd\nea → [[a,1,.],[b,1,.],[c,1,.],[d,1,.],[e,1,.],[a,1,.]]` (contains two `[a,1,.]`, which is a pretty annoying edge case).

Comment: Can we use an alternative to the character ‘0’ for our spacer? e.g. the number 0 (if a list of lists is acceptable input per @JoKing’s comment), or a space character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>52</s> 54 bytes

```
,UŒD€;,Z$ṣ€€”0ŒrẎ€⁺;€"“\/-|”Ẏ2ị$ÐṀ¹F}ḟ”0;€1,”.ʋØ½œị’Ɗ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/18n9Ogkl0dNa6x1olQe7lwMZIFQw1yDo5OKHu7qA3Ead1kDKaVHDXNi9HVrgHJAcaOHu7tVDk94uLPh0E632oc75oO0gJQZ6gBZeqe6D884tPfoZKCqRw0zj3XZ/3e3Buo/tK3m0LawQ9uASqwPtx@d9HDnDBXrR43buQ63A7VG/v8frWQAAUo6SgaGQABhQcVideDyIOFEIICpNUgCAaiSSgODCpiSygqgqiqwkgqguAGYCZSthDBB6oDsKrDG5ORkoFByOZgEskFilmAS5BSgIDIFEk5MAqlMQWEDLU1VigUA)

A monadic link that takes a list of strings and returns. list of maximal outputs each in the order `n, m, d`. A third of the code is to deal with the requirement for dots (last example). Now handles Kevin Cruijssen’s edge case correctly.

Comment: Fails for edge-case `["ab","cd","ea"]`. It only outputs a single `['a', 1, '.']` triplet instead of two. Nice answer regardless, so +1 from me.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I had thought about that, though wasn’t entirely clear what the desired output was. Should be fixable.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Fixed.

Comment: Nice, and a lot shorter than I thought. :) Just 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 110 bytes

```
≔⪫Ａ⸿θＰθＦθ«≔⟦⟧ηＦ∧¬№0⸿ι⟦→↘↓↙⟧«≔ＫＤＬθ✳κζＷ›Ｌζ№ζι≔⊟ζε⊞η⟦κιＬζ⟧»¿⁼¹⌈Ｅη§κ²⊞υ⊟ηＦη⊞υκι»⎚≔⌈Ｅυ§ι²εＦΦυ⁼⊟ιε«⊟ι,Ｉε,Ｐ✳⊟ι⎇⊖ε¹.¦⸿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZLBTsMwDIbP7VNYPaVSQMBxnKYN0NCGJsSt9BB13hK1S7s0ZWNoz16ctKOV6KFx8tvf71jJpDBZKYq2nda12mn2WirNFrpqLIs5RJ8mouUQP4arprCqMkpb5rbb0gAF8BMGfWWScpCkBF6a6g17Ky2blQ1VRHcE4qBigiWTd7WTlsNkXh71OO6XJW5tGnv0lb1GzOfKYGZVqdkS9c5KcucwHOaOfXb@wVGqAoG9GBQWzTX9THrXzdl3EsMVXlZeRF@8bmrJJLWZUxaHv@LUqZcwUFtgT4dGFDW757ASJ7Vv9mwlKlc0tQu9wROj2ofYfeBxDQdnImPHwKJG8DOSg5w7Ze2nqyi8hLMChWEU9k2OjZrBSHVGXfMe@qwKd2nK6bt0zspndDPtXLrTwTXi0bCZidoy/K@O3sAw@J7E4QONFuabzTEzuEdtcUMQDjSm6DYa09yroku2bZJEWZYRPTv6P8Vp2t58Fb8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes an array of strings as input. Explanation:

```
≔⪫Ａ⸿θＰθ
```

Join the strings with carriage returns (not newlines) and output them without moving the cursor.

```
Ｆθ«
```

Loop over each character in the string.

```
≔⟦⟧η
```

Collect all of the consecutive characters starting at this position in an array.

```
Ｆ∧¬№0⸿ι⟦→↘↓↙⟧«
```

If the current character is not a `0` or a carriage return, then check all four directions.

```
≔ＫＤＬθ✳κζ
```

Peek as much as possible in that direction.

```
Ｗ›Ｌζ№ζι≔⊟ζε
```

Shorten the string until all of the characters are the same.

```
⊞η⟦κιＬζ⟧»
```

Save the results in the array.

```
¿⁼¹⌈Ｅη§κ²⊞υ⊟ηＦη⊞υκ
```

If the maximum consecutive character was 1, then only push one of the results to the final array, otherwise push all of them.

```
ι»
```

Reprint the current character, this time allowing the cursor to move.

```
⎚
```

Clear the input from the canvas.

```
≔⌈Ｅυ§ι²ε
```

Find the longest consecutive length.

```
ＦΦυ⁼⊟ιε«
```

Loop over the entries with that length.

```
⊟ι,Ｉε,
```

Output the character and length.

```
Ｐ✳⊟ι⎇⊖ε¹.¦⸿
```

If the length is 1 then output a `.` otherwise output a direction character. Then move to the start of the next line for the next result.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 82 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
í‚εεygÅ0«NFÁ]€ø`IIø)εεγJ0K}˜D€gøNUε"/\-|"XèªćÙš]€`D€ÅsZQÏεDÅsi¤'.:]{γεÐнÅsig4÷∍]€`
```

Input as a matrix of characters. Outputs as a list of triples.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NpHDbPObT23tTL9cKvBodV@bocbYx81rTm8I8HT8/AOTZDUuc1eBt61p@e4AMXTD@/wCz23VUk/RrdGKeLwikOrjrQfnnl0IUhPAkjB4dbiqMDD/ee2ugBZmYeWqOtZxVaf23xu6@EJF/aChNJNDm9/1NEL1vD/f3S0koGSjlIlEBtAcQUS20ApVidaKRHISoSqqoCyYbgKrAJZbyWKfmQVyCZXYqioQNOHrAqoIhYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaRTeWi3jpJ/aQmU5/L/8NpHDbPObT23tTL9cKvBodV@bocba2trHzWtObwjobLy8A5NkOS5zV4G3rWn57gAxdMP7/ALPbdVST9Gt0Yp4vCKQ6uOtB@eeXQhWFMCSMXh1uKowMP957a6AFmZh5ao61nV1laf23xu6@EJF/aCxNJNDm9/1NEL0fJf59A2@//R0dFKBko6OHCsDkTWEA2jyuLQG6ujgNdwmBGJQBYyxu4EEE7CglEsqkTSWoHTokqoLLKlVSgWVaCZZYCiAtnkSgwVFVg8WolQAXEsaoCCtBEUgWhMBnIgGKQExCpH4UHlIIotYYxEcGDB1KTgFAayUsEBEhsbCwA).

**Explanation:**

Generate all diagonals and anti-diagonals of the input-matrix:

```python
í                 # Reverse each row of the (implicit) input-matrix
 ‚                # Pair it with the (implicit) input-matrix
  ε               # Map both matrices to:
   ε              #  Map each row to:
    yg            #   Get the length of the current row
      Å0«         #   Append that many 0s at the end of the row
         NFÁ      #   Rotate the row the 0-based index amount of times towards the right
  ]               # Close the rotate-loop and nested maps
   €ø             # Transpose/zip (swapping rows/columns) for both matrices
     `            # And push both matrices to the stack
```

Put them in a list with the input-matrix itself, as well as all columns of the input-matrix:

```python
I                 # Push the input-matrix
 Iø               # Push the input-matrix, and transpose/zip (swapping rows/columns)
   )              # Wrap everything on the stack into a list
```

Now that we have a list of all diagonals, all anti-diagonals, all rows, and all columns, we're going to extract chunks of the same characters, and transform them into the output triplets:

```python
ε                 # Map each matrix to:
 ε                #  Map each row to:
  γ               #   Split into chunks of the same elements
   J              #   Join them together to a string
    0K            #   Remove all 0s
 }˜               #  After the map of the rows: deep-flatten all chunks
    €g            #  Get the length of each chunk
   D  ø           #  And pair it with the chunk itself
       NU         #  Store the current index in variable `X`
       ε          #  Map over the chunk and length pairs:
        "/\-|"Xè  #   Get the `X`'th character from the string "/\|-"
                ª #   And append it to the pair
        ć         #   Extract head; push the length plus character pair and chunk
                  #   separately to the stack
         Ù        #   Uniquify the chunk so a single character remains
          š       #   And prepend it back in front of the length & character pair
]                 # Close both maps
 €`               # And then flatten once
```

Now that we have all our triplets, we only leave the largest ones:

```python
 €Ås              # Get the middle element (the chunk-length) of each
    Z             # Get the maximum chunk-length (without popping the list itself)
     Q            # Check for each chunk-length if it's equal to this maximum
D     Ï           # And only leave the triplets at the truthy indices
```

And finally we have to fix all `.` edge cases, for chunk-lengths of size 1:

```python
ε                 # Map each triplet:
 DÅsi             #  If the middle element (the chunk-length) is exactly 1:
     ¤'.:        '#   Replace the trailing character of the triplet with a "."
]                 # Close the if-statement and map
 {                # Sort the triplets
  γ               # And group them by the exact same triplets
   ε              # Map each chunk of the same triplets to:
    Ð             #  Triplicate the chunk of triplets
     нÅsi         #  If the middle element of each triplet is 1:
         g        #   Get the amount of the same triplets in this chunk
          4÷      #   Integer-divide it by 4
            ∍     #   And shorten the chunk of triplets to that size
   ]              # Close the if-statement and map
    €`            # Flatten once
                  # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```